# How to extract lines based on regex expression?

Tags: regex

I have a text file like:

```
Input text:output text (doesn't match regex)
Input text2:output text2 (does match regex)
```

Continues on for many lines.

Using the regex expression `:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,20}$` how can I filter out all the output text?

I want the output to be like:

```
Input text2:output2(does match regex)
```

I have seen grep but I am on Windows, what program/how should I accomplish this?

Comment: you'll probably want to go with `for /f` - https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: Someone will likely mention findstr. Don't waste time with findstr. Not only does it not support fancy stuff like lookahead (the `(?=…)` part), it outright crashes with complex regexes.

Comment: There are `grep`-like utilities for Windows (you can use Cygwin for example) or you can install `perl`.